# Como fazer para o usuário não pegar um TXT Inválido?

Tags: delphi

Segue o código:

```delphi
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  txt: TextFile;
  l, treg : integer;
  lTemp: String;
begin
  treg := 1;
  l:= 0;    
  AssignFile(txt, lbCaminho.Caption);
  Reset(txt);
  while not eof(txt) do
    begin
      Readln(txt, lTemp);
      if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E14') then
      begin
        inc(treg);
        sgCupons.RowCount:=treg;
        inc(l);
        //COO
        sgCupons.Cells[0,l] := copy(lTemp,53 ,6);
        //CCF
        sgCupons.Cells[1,l] := copy(lTemp,47 ,6);
        //S/N
        sgCupons.Cells[2,l] := copy(lTemp,4, 20);
        //DATA
        sgCupons.Cells[3,l] := copy(lTemp,59, 8);
      end;
    end;
    CloseFile(txt);
    ShowMessage('Existem '+IntToStr(treg)+' linhas.');
end;
```

Fiz esse código com o intuito de ler o TXT e atribuir as linhas da sringGrid.
Mas o problema agora é que eu quero evitar que o usuário venha ler um arquivo indevido, como um txt qualquer.

Então, eu pensei nesse código:

```delphi
AssignFile(txt, lbCaminho.Caption);
Reset(txt);

if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E09')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E10')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E11')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E12')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E13')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E14')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E15')
and (copy(lTemp, 1, 3)= 'E21')
then
begin
  // O codigo acima viria aqui.
end
else
  ShowMessage('Arquivo .TXT inválido.');

CloseFile(txt);
```

Porem ele entra em um loop e diz que todo arquivo txt é invalido, ou seja, da erro de entrada e saida.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: É mesmo um `and` que você quer, e não um `or`? (não entendo Delphi, mas *me parece* que você está testando um intervalo por alguns valores possíveis - e gostaria que entrasse no `if` se qualquer um desses valores estiver presente. Entendi certo?)

Comment: Entendeu certo mesmo amigo, mas o problema é que mesmo com o 'and' ele esta dando problemas, e fica reconhecendo como 'txt invalido', daí tentei agora com o 'or', mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Exatamente Crood! kkkkk, o poblema msm é o while, eu nao posso colocar esse if DENTRO do while e fechar o arquivo duas vezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com `And` não vai funcionar mesmo.

```delphi
AssignFile(txt, lbCaminho.Caption);
Reset(txt);

if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E09')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E10')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E11')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E12')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E13')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E15')
or (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E21')
then
begin
  // O codigo acima viria aqui.
end
else
begin
  ShowMessage('Arquivo .TXT inválido.');
end;

CloseFile(txt);
```

Precisa ser com `Or`, porque você precisa encontrar pelo menos um desses identificadores, e não todos na mesma posição da mesma `string` ao mesmo tempo.

Muda para isso e certifique-se de estar escolhendo um arquivo válido para testar.
Se o problema persistir você pode estar pegando um valor errado, talvez por uma posição errada.

Teste bem, faça um ***debug*** do código.

Comment: O problema era trocar o `and` pelo `Or` msm cara, porem tinha que trocar o local do código.